# write a program that determines if user input is even or odd and loops

Tags: python, loops, break

I am trying to make a program that will continuously take a user input and determine if the user input is even or odd. The program will only stop when zero is entered.

However, when I enter zero, it `print`s `0 is an even number` followed by `All done!`. The expected output is just `All done!`. Here is my code:

```
def main():
    total = 0
    count = 0

    while True:
        entry=int(input('Enter a number or 0 to quit:'))
        if entry % 2 == 0:
            print (format (entry), 'is an even number.')
        else:
            print (format (entry),'is an odd number.')

        if entry == 0:
            print ('All done!')
            break
main()
```

Comment: make sure your input type is the appropriate one, (string, integer, etc) the indentation of your break seems missplaced

Comment: '0' is even, think about 'X' to quit. and use int(entry) % 2 == 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to check whether the input is zero before doing anything else, do so. If you want to stop the loop in certain conditions, put the `break` inside a conditional. Note that `count` and `total` were unused. Also, `format()` with no formatting is redundant.

```
def main():

    while True:
        entry = int(input('Enter a number or 0 to quit:'))    
        if entry == 0:
            print('All done!')
            break
        if entry % 2 == 0:
            print(entry, 'is an even number.')
        else:
            print(entry, 'is an odd number.')

main()
```

Comment: so by putting the break after the first if, this will stop the program from running the other conditions, correct? @TigerhawkT3

Comment: Python programs are always executed line by line (except for conditionals, loops, function calls and the like).

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that when Python reads your code, it reads it top down. When it reaches `if entry % 2 == 0:` first and will output whatever that is there. Then it continues to `if entry == 0` and outputs whatever that's there again.

What you want is that it should go to one code block only and executes it. You would also want it to prioritize `entry == 0`, so you would move that to the top. In this case, `elif` is the command you seek.

```
def main():
    total = 0
    count = 0

    while True:
        entry=int(input('Enter a number or 0 to quit:'))
        if entry == 0:
            print ('All done!')
            break
        elif entry % 2 == 0:
            print (format (entry), 'is an even number.')
        else:
            print (format (entry),'is an odd number.')
main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check for 0 before the `entry%2==0` condition, ince 0%2==0 it is not breaking the loop.

Secondly use `raw_input` instead of input.

```
def main():
    total = 0
    count = 0

    while True:
        entry=int(raw_input('Enter a number or 0 to quit:'))

        if entry == 0:
            print ('All done!')
            break



        if entry % 2 == 0:
            print (format (entry), 'is an even number.')
        else:
            print (format (entry),'is an odd number.')

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not try something like this

```
if entry == 0:   
     print ('All done!')
     break 
else  if entry % 2 == 0:
     print (format (entry), 'is an even number.')
else:
     print (format (entry),'is an odd number.')
```

Sorry about the wrong indentation. I'm not really familiar with python. Why make it do additional work if all it needs to do at encountering 0 is to end